# reset href attribute after clicking on modal

Tags: javascript, yii2, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have several buttons in gridview to call a bootstrap modal (the same modal but different contents):

```
return Html::a('<i class="fa">&#xf06e;</i> ', $key, [
                'title' => 'Lihat rincian agenda ini',
                'data-bs-toggle' => 'modal',
                'data-bs-target' => '#exampleModal',
                'class' => 'modal-link',
            ]);

return Html::a('<i class="fab text-danger fa-readme"></i> ', ['laporan/' . $model->id_agenda], [
                    'title' => 'Laporan agenda belum disetujui',
                    'data-bs-toggle' => 'modal',
                    'data-bs-target' => '#exampleModal',
                    'class' => 'modal-link',
                ]);
 return Html::a('<i class="fab text-success fa-readme"></i> ', ['laporan/' . $model->id_agenda], [
                    'title' => 'Lihat laporan agenda ini',
                    'data-bs-toggle' => 'modal',
                    'data-bs-target' => '#exampleModal',
                    'class' => 'modal-link',
                ]);
```

This the JS to call the modal:

```js
    $(function () {
    $('.modal-link').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#exampleModal').modal('show').find('#modalContent').load($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

The first click on any button gives the correct contents (href). But the second click and next ones give content from the first click. How do I reset the contents so each click gives accurate href content?

### Update

This is the list of JS library I use in my yii2 app:

```
    'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js',
    'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js',
    'library/restaurantly/assets/vendor/aos/aos.js',
    'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'library/restaurantly/assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js',
    'library/restaurantly/assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js',
    'library/restaurantly/assets/js/main.js',
    'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10/dist/sweetalert2.min.js',
```

I tried removing the list one by one but that only made the page disappear completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to mandy8055. His answer does not work on the whole app but it helps me find another way out of the problem. Here's the updated code that works:

```
$(document).on('click', '.modal-link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var modal = $('#exampleModal');
    modal.find('#modalContent').load(url, function() {
       modal.modal('show');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that the content is being cached after the first load. For this scenario you will have to clear the modal content when the modal is hidden. Below is a sample code that binds an event handler to the ***[`hidden.bs.modal`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#events)*** event.

```js
$(function () {
  // ...rest of your code

  $('#exampleModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('#modalContent').empty();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried it but it's still the same error. The second click gives me this on the console: $(...).modal is not a function, it refers to this line: $('#exampleModal').modal('show').find('#modalContent').load($(this).attr('href'));

Comment: @Safira Is it possible for you to replicate this issue on jsfiddle or codepen? For me this works. [Reference](https://codepen.io/mandy8055/pen/poYrXJb) The problem you mentioned usually happens because of caching.

Comment: I tried isolating my code from my yii2 app and apparently, it works just fine https://codepen.io/khansasafira19/pen/vYPJoBE. But in the app it is still like I stated in the question. Is it because of JS config? I've updated the question with the list of JS in my AppAsset.php.

Comment: What do I do to make it work?

Comment: I can only suggest to debug the issue(like: checking the browser console for any warnings or error messages, checking script conflicts, etc.).